# How to create a Gtk combobox with the interface new_with_area?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gtk#, gtkmm

According to the gtk documentation you can create a combobox with:

```
GtkWidget * gtk_combo_box_new ()
GtkWidget * gtk_combo_box_new_with_entry ()
GtkWidget * gtk_combo_box_new_with_model ()
GtkWidget * gtk_combo_box_new_with_model_and_entry ()
GtkWidget * gtk_combo_box_new_with_area ()
GtkWidget * gtk_combo_box_new_with_area_and_entry ()
```

I have found a lot of examples for the `gtk_combo_box_new_with_model` but I can't find anything related to the use of `gtk_combo_box_new_with_area` .

The langage used doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like (pygobject):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
area = Gtk.CellAreaBox()
combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_area(area=area)
cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
area.pack_start(cell, True, True, True)
```

you can add more CellRenderers to the box (which is a Gtk.Box) and do whatever you need to do with those.